# Is there a difference between store and move methods in laravel file upload and when to use one over the other?

Tags: laravel, file, upload

When uploading images I realize FIRST I can use `store method` which saves images in the `storage/app/public` by default then I'll have to create a `symbolic link` from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` to access the image.

SECOND, I can still use `move method` and have the image saved in the public/images directly.

I feel like the first way is longer for no reason, is there scenarios of when to use one over the other or it's just a matter of preference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's better in some cases, but it might not be relevant to you, let me explain.

The `storage` folder is usually considered a "shared" folder. What I'm trying to say with that is that the contents usually should not change when you deploy your application and most of its contents are usually even ignored in git (to prevent your uploads from ending up in your git repository).

So storing your uploads in this case inside the `storage/app/public` directory means the contents are not in git and the `storage` folder can be shared between deployments.

This is useful when you are using tools like [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/), [Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/envoy) or other "zero downtime" deployment tools.

Most (if not all) zero downtime deployment tools work by cloning your application to a fresh directory and running `composer install` and other setup commands before promoting that fresh directory to the `current` directory which is used by your webserver to serve your app. Changing a symlink over to a new directory is instant and thus you have zero downtime deployments since all setup (installing dependencies etc.) was done in a folder not yet serving traffic to your users.

And since each deployment starts with a fresh clone of your repository that also means that your `public` and `storage` folder are empty again... which is not what you want because you of course want to retain uploads between deployments. A way to work around that is that those deployment tools will have the `storage` folder stored in another folder and with every deployment it clones your git repo and symlinks the `storage` folder to that shared `storage` folder so all your deployments share the same `storage` directory making sure uploads (but depending on the drivers you use also sessions, caches, and logs) are the same for every deployment.

And from there you can use `php artisan:link` to symlink the `storage/app/public` to `public/storage` so that the files are publicly accessible.

(Note: with the symlink in place it doesn't matter to which path your write, `storage/app/public` or `public/storage` because they point to the same folder on the disk).

So this seemingly overcomplicated symlink dance is to make deployments easier and having all your "storage" in a single place, the `storage` dir.

But when you are not using those zero downtime deployment tools this all seems like a lot of nonsense. But even there it still might be useful to have a single place where all your app storage lives for backups for example instead of having to backup multiple directories.

Comment: Makes sense, though I don't have experience with zero downtime deployment tools. I guess these are things one gets to know the importance of one over the other with experience.

Comment: This will come with time, it might seem like complicated nonsense now but once you will have a need for a better deployment strategy it will all fall into place (in theory). But don't be afraid to do things you like it, you did your research and now you know more than before and can make a better decision but it's still your choice.

Comment: I agree with you when you said it might not be relevant to me. In my case and what I'm trying to achieve I don't think it matters but my curiosity is satisfied now and I know I'll come back to refer to this with time.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

from laravel documentation  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem:

> `move` method may be used to rename or move an existing file to a new location

> Laravel makes it very easy to store uploaded files using the `store` method on an uploaded file instance.

So, use `storeAs()` or `store()` when you are working with a file that has been uploaded (i.e. within a controller), and `move()` only when you've already got a file in the disk to move it from one location to another.

Comment: I had come across this explanation but I still couldn't understand why use one over the other. The explanation just states when to use one over the other but not why not use one over the other in those situations and in my case either way achieves my objective.